# Patching AFJSONRequestOperation to check a variable before running?

Tags: iphone, ios, afnetworking, nsoperation

I have an NSOperation, Authenticate, which authenticates with the server.

I have another operation, fetchImage of type AFJSONRequestOperation, which depends on Authenticate from being executed successfully.

This is the flow I want to achieve:

Authenticate -> fetchImage

If authenticate fails, I do not want fetchImage to run at all.

Unfortunately, AFJSONRequestOperation doesn't provide an API for doing things before its request. It only provides an API for dealing what the request has accomplished.

Does anyone have a good solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than changing the fetchImage operation to make something happen *before* it, consider making the fetchImage begin *after* the auth NSOperation, as follows ...

```
NSOperation *authOperation = ...

[authOperation setCompletionBlock:^{
    // start an AFJSONRequestOperation
}];
```

Comment: I wish there's an easy way to do it but this looks like it's the only way